# Titlesec & Titletoc: dangerous relationships

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

Please, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\thechapter}{0pt}{}
%%{\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\chaptertitlename\space \thechapter}{11pt}{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont\itshape}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[1.5em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{}
%{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% codice Pignalberi
\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][l]%
{\textsc{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel\ quad}}}}
{}
{}
{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1 title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section a title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section b title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\chapter{Chapter 2 title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section c title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section d title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\chapter{Chapter 3 title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section e title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section f title}
Some text some text some text some text some text
\end{document}
```

I tried to change, according to my needs, and the index format is ok. As a second step, I'd like to put page numbers in the ToC on left side. But the code I found (in my MWE "codice Pignalberi") interferes with the previous one. For I'm not able to understand, following the titlesec/titletoc manual, where and how to coordinate the two sides of this code, I hope in your help.

===================================================

**UPDATE**

All works very fine now, thanks to Gonzalo's code. I improved two aspect (add more space before chapter titles and remove chapter numbers, leaving only sections' ones: now it looks me more useful to the reader). The code is the following one:

```
<pre>\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[rightlabels,dotinlabels]{titletoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\titlecontents{chapter}[-3pc]
  {\addvspace{0.8pc}}
  {\makebox[3pc][r]{\hfill}%
    \textsc{\thecontentslabel}\quad%
  }
  {}
  {}
  {}
\titlecontents{section}[-3pc]
  {\makebox[4pc][r]{\thecontentspage\hfill}%
    \textsc{\thecontentslabel}\quad%
  }
  {}
  {}
  {}</pre>
```

Lastly, I'd like to align right and not left all numbers (pages and sections), for actually the titles of the section are not well aligned using a proportional font. Consider that the `titletoc` options `rightlabels,dotinlabels` seem to me not working. Thanx a lot!
You can see the problem here:
[image: bad alignement]

==========================================================

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to use etoc copying your code into my .tex file, but the result is very strange:
[image: etoc strange effects]

==========================================================

**UPDATE 3**

The troubles above are due to `bidi` package, for in that file I use Hebrew and Phoenician too. In a "normal" file `etoc` code works fine. Only a last question: I have to read very well `etoc` documentation, which is rather large. But how is it possible to align right page numbers too? thanx!!

Comment: Don't load `titletoc`? Basically, you give 2 definitions of what to do in the TOC for chapters. This obviously creates problems. Assuming you want the second definition, then, dropping the first should work. Obviously if you want the first, you'd drop the second instead. I guess I'm not understanding the question...

Comment: The first code is to give a different format to ToC; it keeps the page numbers in the right. The secondo code ("Pignalbei code") is able to put page numbers on left side, even if it produces further effects. I'd like to mantain my format and translate page numbers in left side. I realize that the two codes are not compatible; but keeping my original format, I don't know how move page numbers on left side...

Comment: So you want page numbers on the left. And where should the chapter number go then?

Comment: What format are you trying to achieve exactly? Since those two lots of code specify different formats for the same elements of the TOC, I'm not very clear how you want to combine them. Which format do you want to maintain?

Comment: I'd like to have all numbers on le left, not only chapters, as in this page: [url]http://liceofranchetti.it/out.png[/url]

Comment: sorry, thet's the right address: http://www.liceofranchetti.it/out.png

Comment: @user41063 Please see my updated answer. Something like that is what you want? Also, please add new information as an edit to your question so everyone can easily see it.

Comment: Sorry for delaying in answer you, but I've 2 children :-) Great solutions, thanx a lot. Yes, there are some possibilities, I'm not yet sure about the format of index. Both Gonzalo's codes are very good to place page numbers every where. Maybe it's not so useful if there are section, so the first one begins in the same page of chapter...

Comment: The last two questions, so all my needs will be satisfied: 1) the way reproduce exactly the page whose image I posted, i.e. without chapter numbers, but only section number? 2) how have page numbers right, and not left, aligned (exacly as in the example I posted)?

Comment: And, last, a bit more space before each chapter title (again exacly as in the example I posted)...

Comment: Actually, I'm considering `titletoc` solution, for I did never use etoc hitherto

Comment: «And, last, a bit more space before each chapter title (again exacly as in the example I posted)»: Solved adding `{\addvspace{0.8pc}}` to `titlecontent`. I don't know, but option `\usepackage[rightlabels,dotinlabels]{titletoc}` are notworking

Comment: By the way, you need not load `fontenc`. `cfr-lm` will load it anyway as it only supports `T1` (and `TS1`).

Comment: Thanx for your elucidation. In any case, in my original file I use EB Garamond and xelatex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a slight variant on that part of [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167267/4686) which uses [`etoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc). I don't know how it behaves in interaction with `bidi`.

With `etoc` things become easier once one has a supply of examples.

Here I have added some graphical aid to understand the layout, particularly for vertical alignment. Section page numbers go to the left margin. Chapters and section numbers are right aligned and there is a `1em` horizontal separation from the actual heading. The chapter names start at `1cm` from the left margin and the section names at `2cm`. Long names wrap at a distance of `1cm` from the right text margin.

The **update** (added at the end) is in response to comments about treating unnumbered chapters and displaying page numbers also for some selected chapters. (both are here illustrated on one unnumbered extra chapter).

> [image: etoc TOC]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,paperwidth=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
% FOR VISUALIZING LAYOUT:
  % {\fboxsep-\fboxrule\noindent\normalsize
  %        \fbox{\makebox[1cm][r]{\strut
  %                          \smash{\color{blue}\vrule depth12cm}\hspace{1em}%
  %                          \smash{\color{green}\vrule depth12cm}}}%
  %        \fbox{\makebox[1cm][r]{\color{blue}\strut
  %                          \smash{\color{blue}\vrule depth12cm}\hspace{1em}%
  %                          \smash{\color{green}\vrule depth12cm}}}%
  %        \fbox{\makebox[1cm]{\strut}}(debugging layout)\hfill
  %        \fbox{\makebox[1cm][l]{\strut\smash{\color{red}\vrule
  %              depth12cm}}}%
  %   \hrule}  
  {}% <- uncomment the above and suppress this line if debugging layout
  {\pagebreak[3]\vskip25pt\leftskip 1cm\relax
                          \rightskip 1cm\relax
                          \parindent 0pt\relax
   }
  {\Large\leavevmode
   \llap{\makebox[1cm][r]{\normalsize\etocnumber.\hspace{1em}}}%
   \etocname\par\nopagebreak\medskip }
  {\bigskip}


\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}  
  {\leftskip 2cm\relax}
  {\normalsize\leavevmode
   \llap{\makebox[1cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}%
                    \hspace{1cm}%
                    \makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber.\hspace{1em}}}%
   \etocname\par\pagebreak[1]\smallskip }
  {}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Vita e Opere}
\setcounter{page}{98}% just for the example
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Infanzia, studi a Lipsia e soggiorno a Parigi}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Della \textit{Dissertazione preliminare} al \textit{Dialogo}}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{La concezione delle idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\chapter{Seggni (``caratteri'') e idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Della \textit{Dissertazione preliminare} al \textit{Dialogo}}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{La concezione delle idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\clearpage

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\end{document}
```

---

> [image: etoc TOC 2]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,paperwidth=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}


%% ETOC SPECIFICATIONS

% conditional to display chapter page number
% a priori set to false
\newif\ifDisplayInTocChapterPageNumber

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {\pagebreak[3]\vskip25pt\leftskip 1cm\relax
                          \rightskip 1cm\relax
                          \parindent 0pt\relax
   }
  {\Large\leavevmode
   \llap{\ifDisplayInTocChapterPageNumber
             \makebox[1cm][r]{\mdseries\normalsize\etocpage}%
         \fi
         \makebox[1cm][r]{\normalsize\etocifnumbered{\etocnumber.}{}%
                          \hspace{1em}}}%
   \etocname\par\nopagebreak\medskip }
  {\bigskip}


\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}  
  {\leftskip 2cm\relax}
  {\normalsize\leavevmode
   \llap{\makebox[1cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}%
                    \hspace{1cm}%
                    \makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber.\hspace{1em}}}%
   \etocname\par\pagebreak[1]%\smallskip 
  }
  {}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Vita e Opere}
\setcounter{page}{98}% just for the example
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Infanzia, studi a Lipsia e soggiorno a Parigi}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Della \textit{Dissertazione preliminare} al \textit{Dialogo}}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{La concezione delle idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\chapter{Seggni (``caratteri'') e idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Della \textit{Dissertazione preliminare} al \textit{Dialogo}}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{La concezione delle idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\clearpage

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\DisplayInTocChapterPageNumbertrue}

\chapter*{Un capitolo non numerato e col numero di pagina nel margine dell'indice}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Un capitolo non numerato e col numero di
  pagina nel margine dell'indice}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Ultimi anni}
Some text some text some text some text some text


\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I was just reading the edit 3 to the question, but now you've provided a solution. I just want to thank you for letting me know the `etoc` package (in the last days I´ve seen some of the answers you've provided using it). I had never before used it myself, but with this question I decided to give it a try. It's really powerful!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `:-)` the manual has examples but some are not developed enough, others are too specific (like doing a `tree` or a  `table`). I now stabilized on the kind of technique used in section `5` of the manual `a second example`, or the one from section `31.5` `using depth tags`.

Comment: Great! I made some little changes to format (i.e. titles in 11pt as the text...). A question and a problem. 1) How decrease line-spacing in the ToC? I'd like to have the same normal line-spacing of the normal text. 2) I've two chapters, Bibliography and Index (with `imakeidx`) which are \chapter*. Your code produces the titles with a (worthless) period before. More, I know that in the other chapters there is no page number (that's ok for me), but in these two cases (there is no `\section` here) it would be suitable to supply it. Is it feasible?

Comment: By trials and errors I solved for line-spacing (discovering the role of `\smallskip` inside the code). It remains the problem of starred chapters

Comment: @user41063 see updated answer. The `\etocifnumbered{YES}{NO}` switch allows to adapt code to presence or absence of a sectioning number. For decidnig to display or no the page number, one can use a specific boolean, and add it to the `.toc` file. see the code.

Comment: @user41063 for unnumbered chapters it could be more pleasing to reclaim the space used for the number, you can easily adapt the code to do that just use a big `\etocifnumbered{what to do if numbered}{what to do if not numbered}`

Comment: Very good working solution (I changed only some details to save space in ToC). However, i don't understand what exactly does @user41063 mean in his last post...

Comment: sorry, a bad copy/past... Obviously i refer to jfbu saying «it could be more pleasing to reclaim the space used for the number»

Answer (score 9):

Below I show two options; the first one uses `etoc` and the second one, `titletoc`. The final desired formatting is still not completely clear to me. The question asks to place page numbers for chapter os the left, and then an image is provided in the comments in which chapter entries don't have page numbers to the left? Anyway, the example code below allow for easy customizations to achieve whatever format is desired.

One possibility using the powerful [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,paperwidth=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}  
  {\vskip25pt\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\parbox[t]{.5cm}{\etocnumber.\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-15pt\relax}{\Large\etocname}\hfill\par\medskip
  }
  {}
\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}  
  {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{\mdseries\hfill\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\parbox[t]{1cm}{\quad\etocnumber.\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-15pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Vita e Opere}
\setcounter{page}{98}% just for the example
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Infanzia, studi a Lipsia e soggiorno a Parigi}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Della \textit{Dissertazione preliminare} al \textit{Dialogo}}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{La concezione delle idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\chapter{Seggni (``caratteri'') e idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Della \textit{Dissertazione preliminare} al \textit{Dialogo}}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{La concezione delle idee}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\clearpage

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{A Honovver, al servizio del ducchi Johann Friedrich ed Ernst August}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Viaggio in Italia, morte dell'elettore Erns August ed successione del nuovo elettore, Georg Ludwig}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another possibility using `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\titlecontents{chapter}[-4pc]
  {\makebox[2pc][l]{\hfill\thecontentspage}\hspace{2pc}%
    \textsc{\thecontentslabel}\quad%
  }
  {}
  {}
  {}
\titlecontents{section}[-4pc]
  {\makebox[2pc][l]{\hfill\thecontentspage}\hspace{3pc}%
    \textsc{\thecontentslabel}\quad%
  }
  {}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1 title}
\setcounter{page}{98}% just for the example
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section a title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section b title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\chapter{Chapter 2 title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section c title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section d title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\chapter{Chapter 3 title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section e title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\section{Section f title}
Some text some text some text some text some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm very grateful to u. Please, see my adds above...

Comment: @user41063 I've updated my answer with the new requirements and using the `etoc` package. In some minutes I'll alos add the option with `titletoc`. But, you should consider using `etoc`; it's a really poerful package :)

Comment: @user41063 Answer updated with titletox. However, this option has some problems (longer titles won't behave well). My suggestion would be to switch to the etoc solution instead.

Comment: You're right, etoc works better. However, it produces a strange result on my file. I put image above, in my originale post

Comment: @user41063 I recommend using `\tstyle` for the numbering here. It is too tabular-like for proportional figures to look right (but you probably want to keep OSF for consistency if these are used for numbering in the document itself).

Comment: @user41063 I am confused by your edit 3. My answer with etoc in the last edit I did right aligns the page numbers. Am I missing something?

Comment: Spacing between items with the solution based on `etoc` is wrong (this is better seen if you remove the g in August). I presume it's due to the `\parbox`es (not to `etoc` itself).

Comment: «Spacing between items with the solution based on etoc is wrong»: and which solution is better?

Comment: @user41063 I don't know, because I've never used `etoc`, but as I said the problem comes very likely from the `\parbox`es, not from `etoc` itself. Trying to build `vertical` text by stacking boxes is not usually a good idea, because interlines may not be properly set.

Answer (score 5):

If I've understood correctly your layout, here is a basic solution based on `titletoc`:

```
\newcommand\boxedpage{\makebox[3pc][r]{\thecontentspage}}
\newcommand\boxedtocnum{\makebox[3pc][r]{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
  {\addvspace{0.8pc}}
  {\contentslabel[\boxedpage\boxedtocnum]{6pc}}
  {}{}{}
\titlecontents{section}[3pc]
  {}
  {\contentslabel[\boxedpage\hspace*{3pc}\boxedtocnum]{9pc}}
  {}{}{}
```

Just play with dimens.

**EDIT.** Here is a complete example with `titletoc`. Remember you can control the numbering with `secnumdepth`, and the included entries in the TOC with `tocdepth`. Remember also with `titletoc` you can change the format of TOC entries in the *middle* of the document (for subsequent sections), if for some reason you need it. As before, just play with dimens.

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand\boxedpage{\makebox[3pc][r]{\thecontentspage}}
\newcommand\boxedtocnum{\makebox[3pc][r]{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}

\titlecontents{chapter}[3pc]
  {\addvspace{0.8pc}}
  {\contentslabel[\boxedpage\boxedtocnum]{6pc}}
  {\contentslabel[\boxedpage\hspace*{3pc}]{6pc}}
  {}{}
\titlecontents{section}[6pc]
  {}
  {\contentslabel[\boxedpage\hspace*{3pc}\boxedtocnum]{9pc}}
  {\contentslabel[\boxedpage\hspace*{6pc}]{9pc}}
  {}{}

\newcommand*\asection{
\section{A Honovver, text text al servizio del ducchi Johann
  Friedrich ed Ernst August.}
Some text some text some text some text some text\par}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Vita e Opere}
\setcounter{page}{98}% just for the example

\asection\asection

\chapter{Seggni (``caratteri'') e idee}

\asection\asection\asection\asection\asection
\asection\asection\asection\asection\asection

% From now on, unnumbered headers, but still in the toc
% down to section
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}\ignorespaces}

\chapter{Seggni (``caratteri'') e idee}

\asection\asection

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ javier Compiling, I receive the following error: `(./zzz.bbl) [1] (./zzz.toc
! Undefined control sequence.
l.43 \DisplayInTocChapterPageNumbertrue
                                       
?`

Comment: @user41063 This comes from your code. I presume you are adding it somehow (or not adding it).

Comment: Thanx to you too. Now I'm simply spoiled for choice!